# fsolve No Solution which options should I try?

Tags: matlab, matrix, solver

I am using `fsolve` in a larger script. `fsolve` returns `No solution found`. I am trying to find rows of a matrix in a for loop which adhear to certain restrictions. This has helped me for previous rows `optimoptions('fsolve', 'Algorithm', 'levenberg-marquardt')`. Now, I am stuck because I do not know which other options make sense. I did not have any luck trying different options without understanding them.

**This is the code which returns** `No solution found`

```
options1 = optimoptions('fsolve', 'Algorithm', 'levenberg-marquardt');
[gamma_k_1y, fval, exitflag, ~] = fsolve(@(gamma_k_1y) f_gamma( gamma_k_1y, m, bstar(k), Lstar, min(y,m) ), zeros(min(y,m),1), options1);
```

**This is the function which I would like to solve**

```
function F = f_gamma( gamma_1y, m, bstar_k, Lstar, y )
%UNTITLED3 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
F(1) = sum( gamma_1y ); % row sum zero
F(2) = sum( gamma_1y.^2 ) - m; % elements squared = m
F(3) = sum( (Lstar(1,1:y).^2) * gamma_1y) - m * bstar_k; % first row squared times new row = m times element od bstar
n_assigned_rows = sum(~isnan(Lstar(:,1)));
for i=1:n_assigned_rows
     F(i+3) = Lstar(i,1:y) * gamma_1y; %element wise multiplication with each row except self zero
end

end
```

**These are my variables**

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Generated by MATLAB on 18-Jul-2017 11:17:31
%  MATLAB version: 9.2.0.538062 (R2017a)
% -------------------------------------------------------------------

Lstar = ...
  [1.9193221763392923 -1.8182365289779376 -0.10108564736135461 0 0 0 0;
   -0.054995957568300745 0.045658192660796168 -1.8654711092538141 1.8748088741613205 ...
   0 0 0;
   -0.045613771137015049 0.011357535373129623 -1.0703617279866948 -1.0666452698891478 ...
   2.1712632336401225 0 0;
   -0.010566489657722691 -0.0548196464049537 0.78541897633795066 0.78253217221128113 ...
   0.77167395707940156 -2.2742389695659573 0;
   -0.024717877486905307 -0.059891167589263682 0.60794721966412446 0.60565273026541278 ...
   0.59702240468188983 0.62248826258542045 -2.348501572120679;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN];

alpha = [1.9193221763392923 -1.8182365289779376 -0.10108564736135461 0 ...
         0 0 0];

b = [1; 1; 1; 1; 2; 1; 1];

beta = [-0.054995957568300745 0.045658192660796168 -1.8654711092538141 ...
        1.8748088741613205 0 0 0];

beta_14 = [-0.054995957568300745; 0.045658192660796168; -1.8654711092538141; ...
           1.8748088741613205];

bstar = [0.15118578920369091; -0.010101525445522112; -0.020203050891044225; ...
         -0.030304576336566323; -0.040406101782088436; 0.020203050891044225; ...
         0.010101525445522112];

exitflag = -2;

fval = [-4.2566077443698074 -2.221444134718805 1.5553705289078517 -0.64353855088729561 ...
        0.042998187795194528 0.085996469204826287 0.12899460131301721 0.17199288121327205 ...
        ];

gamma_k_1y = [0.050858405964284731; 0.45946005395777284; -0.93242551108612626; ...
              -0.91454430220858973; -0.8706585765149597; -1.0001539165810418; ...
              -1.0491438979011476];

gamma_k_ym = saveVarsMat.gamma_k_ym; % <1x0 double> empty object

j = 7;

k = 6;

m = 7;

n = 20;

omega = ...
  [0.3779644730092272 0.70710678118654746 0 0 0 0 0;
   0.3779644730092272 -0.70710678118654746 0.70710678118654746 0 0 0 0;
   0.3779644730092272 0 -0.70710678118654746 0.70710678118654746 0 0 0;
   0.3779644730092272 0 0 -0.70710678118654746 0.70710678118654746 0 0;
   0.3779644730092272 0 0 0 -0.70710678118654746 0.70710678118654746 0;
   0.3779644730092272 0 0 0 0 -0.70710678118654746 0.70710678118654746;
   0.3779644730092272 0 0 0 0 0 -0.70710678118654746];



x = 1.9193221763392923;

y = 8;

z = -0.10108564736135461;
```

I know there is a solution because R can solve this with `nleqslev` while specifying the option `allowSingular=TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's nothing but did you try another initial point. Here I see that you set x0 = zeros(min(y,m),1). Is there a reason why it should start at this point? I'm just asking. 
 
Maybe try x0 = unifrnd(a,b) (You chose a and b) inside a loop, so it will try to "fsolve" starting at a different point at each iteration. 
 
Hope it helps